# Passing Associative array through Amazon API Gateway?

Tags: java, php, android, aws-api-gateway

I am using API gateway for my api resources. I want client to pass filter in query string as an associative array like:

```
/photos?filter[from]=20-10-2015%2010:10:00&filter[to]=20-10-2015%2010:10:00
```

Note: its PHP so on my backend i can get it as associative array. I tried by adding filter as query parameters like

[image]

Using Android Api gateway client is passing `filter` as `"['from':'20-10-2016 10:10:00','to':'20-10-2016 10:10:00’]”` and its getting `Unparseable date: "20-10-2016 10:10:00" (at offset 10)` error.

---

Note: Tried to debug the issue and encountered that its because of date returned in response. On Java SDK its expect in date format. In response i am returning `2015-10-11 12:11:30`.

I am returning

```
{
  "schedule_date": "2015-10-20",
  "completion_date": "2015-10-20",
}
```

What should be the possible format in response?

Comment: How would you parse the date? Can you share your parsing code?

Comment: @KaHouIeong actually i haven't written parsing code, its done by SDK internally

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway does not currently support `[]` in querystring parameters. You will need to add these as 2 distinct parameters.